# WB Como fazer uso do Profile do Android Studio?

Tags: flutter

Quando estamos trabalhando com desenvolvimento em Android com **Java** ou **Kotlin** normalmente é usando um recurso semelhante ao do ListView, porém em dispositivos Android se a lista for muito grande o aplicativo começa a carregar demasiadamente a memória do aparelho telefônico, para contornar esse problema é utilizado uma biblioteca chamada RecyclerView.

Para que seja possível o analise do carregamento em memória é necessário o recurso do Profile do Android Studio como mostra na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando esse botão for acionado a aplicação deveria ser executada em módulo de Profile, e sendo somente assim seria possível verificar se não está havendo carregamento demasiado da memória. Eu tentei realizar um teste no aplicativo dessa aula colocando 10 mil registros e não conseguir acionar o Profile por causa dessa mensagem de erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Existe uma maneira de usar o botão do Profile em aplicativos Flutter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia tentar entender a mensagem de erro primeiramente, certo? Se está em inglês, tente traduzi-la...

Em inglês:

> Exception: Profile mode is not supported for emulators.

Traduzindo para portugûes:

> Exceção: O modo perfil não é suportado em emuladores.

Eu fui e testei, rodei o Profile Mode (PF) num emulador Android e obtive o mesmo erro que você, então pluguei meu celular e testei nele, e olha só, funcionou certinho:

[image: Profile Mode]

**Observações**

Com Flutter você pode usar também o [DevTools](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/overview) para verificar o que deseja, pois traz um detalhamento melhor.

Se você quer algo parecido com o `RecyclerView` do Nativo, utilize o `ListView.builder`, e de uma olhadinha também na propriedade `addAutomaticKeepAlives`.